# crushed inevitability

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*How I met my certain fate by Stewart Lee*

> I don’t do Pull Back and Reveal [type of joke] any more. Instead, with
>   painful slowness, I raise a ratty curtain that was covering something
>   which we had already seen quite clearly anyway through holes in the
>   tattered fabric, and display it shamefacedly, with an air of **crushed
>   inevitability**, as if to say, ‘Here you are. Is this what you wanted?
>   Are you happy now? Do you feel entertained?

I'm stuck on this **"crushed inevitability"**. Who had crushed it? Or is it the author who was crushed (defeated)? But why not use **"with an air of inevitability *as being* crushed"**.

Is there a rule in English that explains it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no rule that explains it. It is metaphor - or in this case I suggest it is metonymy: it is, as you suggest, that the author is feeling crushed at that point (hence the "shamefacedly"). But it is allusive writing, and your paraphrase would be more explicit, and so weaker in a literary sense.

Comment: @ColinFine thanks. Never came across such metaphors

Comment: I've you've come across a particular metaphor before, it's probably a cliche! Much of the point of metaphor in writing is to give it freshness.